# tufte-latex warning: Failed to convert input string to UTF16

Tags: xetex, tufte

I've been receiving this warnings every time I compile a document with tufte-latex class:

```
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
```

Nothing happens, the document compiles fine, but what do those warnings mean?

Here is a minimum working example - it works fine with pdfTeX, but produces the warning with XeTeX:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\begin{document}
\part{A Tale of Two Cities}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited the question with a much shorter MWE that reproduces the problem for me - I'd appreciate reopening the question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a warning from `xdvipdfmx`. It tries to convert the bookmark string from UTF-8 to UTF-16BE, but the string is already provided as UTF-16BE. Thus it is a good thing that
the conversion failed. There are many places, where the PDF structures expect byte strings.
Thus this auto-conversion of PDF strings is very annoying. But I failed to convince the maintainers, see the thread in the XeTeX mailing list ["Anchor names"](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2011-November/021870.html) in November of 2011.

Thus for the time being ignore the warning (and hope for the best).